# How to advance a version string in a file hosted on GitHub?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a repository on GitHub, I want the repository to alter a specific file every time there is a commit/push to include the revision number as part of the version string.

i.e. My version string looks like so:

```
/**
 * Filename
 * @version 1.0.{REVISION}
 */
```

I want the {REVISION} string to be replaced with the relevant revision number.

Is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is commonly called "RCS tags".

You will have to rely on git filter to do the job. Googling around brought the following [GitHub project](https://github.com/turon/git-rcs-keywords).

Assuming that by "revision number" you actually mean "commit ID", then your header would become:

```
/**
 * Filename
 * @version 1.0.$Revision$
 */
```

This is however in many scenarios considered as redundant information (although it's merely a matter of personal preference).

Answer (score 0):

The ProGit book has [details on how to implement keyword expansion](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion).